# Styling openlayers draw interaction

Tags: drawing, openlayers, styling

In the default openlayers draw interaction, there is no line segment which connects where your mouse is to the finish point (first image).  When I set up a custom style, this segment is present which I don't want (second image).  Does anyone know how I eliminate this final segment, like the default style does?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a style function that can style points, lines and polygons and distinguish by the geometry's type. Important: the polygon style should only have a fill, not a stroke. Because the boundary of the polygon is a separate linestring. A minimal working style function for the draw interaction would look like this:

```
var styles = {
  Point: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle()
  }),
  LineString: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke()
  }),
  Polygon: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill()
  })
};
function styleFunction(feature) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType();
}
```